# I keep getting this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver using Selenium trying to open Chrome

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am getting a complilation error when I try to run Selenium Webdriver.

I am using Eclipse and Java inside Eclipse.

I:

Went ahead and downloaded Selenium Server (4.3.0), the language-specific client drivers Java (4.3.0), and the stable release of the latest chrome drivers (got it from here - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=103.0.5060.134/). I had to download the 32 bit version even though my computer is 64 bit, but I only saw a 64 bit version for Windows.

Configured build path and added external jars to build path from the Selenium server file I downloaded.

The code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstSeleniumTest {

    WebDriver driver; 
    public void launchBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\zachw\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        FirstSeleniumTest obj = new FirstSeleniumTest ();
        obj.launchBrowser();

    } 

}
}
```

and keep getting this error:

Error: Unable to initialize main class FirstSeleniumTest
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
Can anyone tell me why I am getting this compilation error and how to fix it?

Comment: Your code is correct, but you are missing selenium dependency in your [project. Better to create a maven project and add selenium web driver dependency in it.

Comment: What do you mean? can you explain this a little further? And how would I do this?

Comment: try this - https://www.edureka.co/blog/create-selenium-maven-project/  and add Selenium 4.x and WebDriverManager dependencies, so you don't need to download exe files manually